# How do I push an object to array in TS? (expected ',' 1005)

Tags: typescript

I've got a very simple code snippet that is not working for some reason.

```
  const arrOfObjects:any[] = [];

  const elems = [
    {
        "ResultRow": "1",
        "ElementIdentifier": "A",
    },
    {
        "ResultRow": "2",
        "ElementIdentifier": "B",
        
    }, 
]

elems.map(elem => arrOfObjects.push({elem.ElementIdentifier:5}))
```

Can someone please explain why it's throwing (expected ',' 1005) error cause it doesn't make any sense to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that `{elem.ElementIdentifier:5}` is not valid JS or TS. If you want to use the ElementIdentifier from that elem as a key, you need to use computed property syntax: `{[elem.ElementIdentifier]: 5}`

Comment: thanks, time to go to bed I guess.